# Javascript/NodeJS Regex(phone nr) invalid group error

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

The following regex looks fine when I try it on regex101.com but it doesn't work on my Javascript (both browser & nodejs).

```
(?i)(\+?[0-9\(][0-9\- \(\)\.]{6,16}( ?e?xt?\.? ?\d+)?)
```

What's the right regex for javascript?

P.S:

Some cases here:

```
650-283-4757
 +1 6502834757
 +33 4 76095663
 06 2070 2220
 (650)-283-4757 ext 897
+355 693502415
```

Comment: What is the regex expected to do?

Comment: When testing JS regex in regex101 you should switch to JS mode. It will show you `(?i)` as defect part, as inline modifiers are not supported by JS regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of inline modifier `(?i)`. JS won't support modifiers which are included in the regex pattern.

```
/(\+?[0-9\(][0-9\- \(\)\.]{6,16}( ?e?xt?\.? ?\d+)?)/i
```

So you have to add the modifiers next to the pattern delimiters `/`

Comment: @TediÇela If you like it so much, please accept Avinash's answer.

Comment: @Cobus Kruger I couldn't accept the answer because it was very quick :). I mean SO prohibited me to accept answer within 10 min after I asked.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark on the beginning of the first group is invalid character.

**Invalid**

```
(?i)(\+?[0-9\(][0-9\- \(\)\.]{6,16}( ?e?xt?\.? ?\d+)?)
```

**Maybe you meant**

```
(?:i)(\+?[0-9\(][0-9\- \(\)\.]{6,16}( ?e?xt?\.? ?\d+)?)
```

Which marks the first group as "non-capturing".

**Or you meant**

```
/(\+?[0-9\(][0-9\- \(\)\.]{6,16}( ?e?xt?\.? ?\d+)?)/i
```

Which marks regex for ignoring case.

Next time i deeply recommend you to test regexes on regexr.com

Comment: As you deeply recommend regexr - what are the advantages over using regex101 in JS mode?